# Animal with no predators

Tags: phrase-requests

We have *apex predators* for animals that have no natural predators.  But it only applies to animals that are themselves predators.

Are there more concise or pithy terms for "animals/organisms with no natural predators" that would encompass herbivores?

Comment: For example, elephants? Any others?

Comment: Also, you may get more expert advice about technical language from a dedicated site like biology.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Mitch Elephants totally can become prey of wild cats. I am struggling to think of any herbivore that no carnivore would kill and eat when given the opportunity.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Many whales.  Also I believe there are lower animals and plants that are so toxic that nothing eats them.

Comment: Plankton is not a vegetable or shroom, so whales are apex predators alright. Poisonous animals and plants are a fair point I guess, but you can go ahead and call them just apex consumers or apex species or what have you. When the word *predator* does not apply, you don't have to use it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt If biological terminology experts don't reply here, I think 'apex consumer' is inclusive enough.

Comment: Can a species be its own predator? If not, *homo sapiens*, today: natural predators practically nonexistent.

Answer (score 4):

The term **apex species** is fitting. This term is not widespread, but, being obviously related to "apex predator", it will be easily understood. The term is used [here](http://blog.nature.org/conservancy/2011/07/20/conservation-apex-species-predator-peter-kareiva/), for example.

After looking further into this, I found some evidence that the term is used research papers:

> - ... apex species (i.e. those at the top of a food chain)...
>      <sub>[Understanding impacts of fisheries bycatch on marine megafauna](http://atlanticsharks.org/papers/Lewison_et_al_2004.pdf)</sub>
> - Mugger crocodile is a
>     predatory apex species in the wetland ecosystem...
>     <sub>[POPULATION STATUS OF THE MUGGER IN CHITWAN NATIONAL PARK, NEPAL.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Babu_Lamichhane/publication/266517675_POPULATION_STATUS_OF_THE_MUGGER_IN_CHITWAN_NATIONAL_PARK_NEPAL/links/5433d5230cf2bf1f1f264614.pdf)</sub>

---

You might also be interested in the term **megafauna**, which includes megaherbivores. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megafauna):

> Megafauna – in the sense of the largest mammals and birds – are generally K-strategists, with high longevity, slow population growth rates, low mortality rates, and (at least for the largest) few or no natural predators capable of killing adults.

Megafauna includes a number of species that aren't very large, like white-tailed deer and humans.

Comment: Or "apex consumer".  For a reference, see http://blog.nature.org/conservancy/2011/07/20/conservation-apex-species-predator-peter-kareiva/, which actually uses both terms.

Comment: @DougWarren Hey that's my source! They define it as synonymous with "apex predator", but it may be used for non-predators, I guess.

Comment: "Apex species" is vague.  What feature is it atop -- a hill?

Comment: @AmI Is it really that different from the phrase *apex predators*? It's really just a variation on another phrase, which gives "apex" a very specific definition.

Comment: 'Apex predator' means 'at the apex of predators' {and not, of course, 'a predator of apexes'}, but 'apex species' would mean 'at the apex of species' -- which of the many things that species do defines the direction of this apex?

Comment: @AmI Like I said, this phrase mirrors "apex predator", so logically the "apex species" are those at the top of their food chain (or food web, if you prefer). I've added some good citations for the term, which seems to be quite popular in academic writing.

Comment: .. and like I implied: 'predator' is much more closely related to 'food chain' than 'species' is.  {'Species' is more about 'procreation'}  The term may be accepted by biologists, but not for a good reason.

Comment: "Megafauna includes a number of species that aren't very large, like white-tailed deer and humans." To be fair, we only think those species aren't very large because we humans are pretty large (as species go). The vast majority of fauna are a lot smaller than humans.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be 'species not subject to predation'.

(Note: 'unpredated' also comes to mind; I have not been able to find an authoritative dictionary-based source to back this up, but the word is definitely used. For example:

'Distance of predated and unpredated nests of Honey Buzzard to the next Goshawk nest at the two study sites (means ± standard errors).'
Source:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/264409021_fig1_Figure-2-Distance-of-predated-and-unpredated-nests-of-Honey-Buzzard-to-the-next-Goshawk )

Comment: 'unpredated' is a clear and accurate coinage.

Answer (score 1):

**Top of its food chain**

**EDIT**: initially I used *top of the* but have changed answer to *top of its* to emphasise there may multiple food chains with various *tops*.

> **food chain**
>   noun 1.(ecology) a sequence of **organisms** in an ecosystem in which each species is the food of the next member of the chain
>   — [Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 2012 Digital Edition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/food-chain)

An [organism](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=organism%20definition) is

> an individual animal, plant, or single-celled life form.

So using the above definitions at the top of a food chain, you find organisms (which may or may not be predators themselves) without natural predators.

To better show the multiple food chain approach here is snippet from a  [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/z2m39j6/revision/2) revision page.

> A food web is a network of interconnected food chains. It shows the energy flow through part of an ecosystem. The diagram is an example
>   [image]
>
> The example above contains lots of information. Here are three food chains from it:
>
> - oak tree → squirrel → fox.
> - oak tree → earthworm → wood mouse → fox.
> - oak tree → earthworm → wood mouse → owl.

Comment: Having no natural predators is not the same as being at the top of the food chain.

Comment: This isn't quite right because again it suggests that the animals on top are eating other animals (the next in the "chain").  E.g., consider whales (so big they are virtually immune to predation) that eat plankton (which are at the *bottom* of the food chain).

Comment: @Centaurus Can you clarify? I can't see how they are not the same!

Comment: @feetwet I deliberately picked a dictionary definition that talks about sequence of organisms rather than a sequence of animals - I have seen both.

Comment: @k1eran    Take for instance the remora and the barnacle.  They spend their whole lives attached to whales or sharks, have no natural predators and are not considered to be at the top of the food chain.  A biologist would certainly have much more to say about this.

Comment: @Centaurus It seems to me there are very many food chains out there some with a few links and some with many. And the little barnacle if nothing preys on it is at the top of its little unglamorous food chain. Caveat is that I am basing this on a couple of specific dictionary definitions and can't say if they are the  ones a biologist would use!

Comment: @centaurus Barnacles have no predators? Meet the dog whelk, a "predatory sea snail": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_whelk

Comment: The colloquial phrase uses "the", so this is more likely to sound odd and be confusing that to adequately specify the situation.

Comment: .. then "Apex of its food chain" might be accurate and less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***inviolable***

> mid-15c., "that is to be kept without violation" (of an oath, etc.),
>   from Latin inviolabilis "inviolable, invulnerable," from in- "not,
>   opposite of" (see in- (1)) + violabilis "that may be injured, easily
>   wounded," from violare "to do violence to" (see violation). Meaning
>   "**having a right or guaranty of immunity**" (of a place of sanctuary,
>   etc.) is from 1570s. Meaning "incapable of being injured" is from
>   1520s. Related: Inviolably.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inviolable

I think it would be accurate to say that such an animal is "inviolable".